# why each method is invoked?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I found this example code excerpt from Sinatra README webpage

```
class Stream
  def each
    100.times { |i| yield "#{i}\n" }
  end
end

get('/') { Stream.new }
```

when I get to the `'/'` path, it seems invoke the each method on `Stream.new` object, why is it?

Answer (score 0):

`each` is called on a stream object, not on the `Stream` class. To get a stream object, you need to do `Stream.new`.